Swagger API with parameters interdependencies for executing an API (fastAPI)
I have a fastAPI end point. I wanted to test the API endpoint using swagger UI. I have two input params for the API endpoint. Based on the choice of the first input, the second input is furnished. For example, if input1 = "example1", the second input for the API must have this construct for the values to be furnished for input2 = {'a':val1,'b':val2}.                     If input1 = "example2", the second input for the API must have this construct; input2 = {'i': val3, 'j': val4}
The API must be executed based on the method defined (in python) for the endpoint and with the inputs - input1 and input2.
I am not getting on how to simulate in swagger UI for testing the API. Please advise.
